# Get 1 frame of swf and save it as image on server

Tags: javascript, php, flash

In order to create a thumbail is possible to get the first frame ( or x- frame ) of a .swf file and then save it to server side as image (jpg, png etc..)

The flash files, are embedded on the html web page. Im searching for a script that can extract the first frame of swf and convert it as image.

is this possible using any php extension/class or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

(Insufficient reputation to comment.) You should probably be more specific. *What OS are you running? What is the flash file, is it embedded on the web page, or is it a standalone file? What have you tried, and are you able to install any libraries?*

If you can provide the answers to those questions, the answer will be much simpler to provide.